# Spring boot convert web.xml listener

Tags: spring, listener, spring-boot, web.xml

I'm trying to convert my project to Spring Boot project (executable jar file with Jetty embedded).
All works with a standard example but I want migrate my old web.xml to Spring Boot.

I migrated Servlet and Filters but I don't understand how migrate filters as this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.granite.config.GraniteConfigListener</listener-class> 
</listener> 
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.granite.gravity.websocket.GravityWebSocketDeployer</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I created my @SpringBootApplication class and I wrote inside all the configuration:

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public FilterRegistrationBean springSecurityFilterChain() {     
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    DelegatingFilterProxy delegatingFilterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
    filterRegBean.setFilter(delegatingFilterProxy);
    List<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<String>();
    urlPatterns.add("/*");
    filterRegBean.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
    return filterRegBean;
}
```

Someone can explain me how Listeners should be converted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For RequestContext read [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java)

```
 @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(RequestContextListener.class)
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }
```

For the other listener is register automatically when you use spring-boot as [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/web/SpringBootServletInitializer.java) link implies.

For your own listeners.

```
public class MyAdditionListeners extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext rootAppContext = createRootApplicationContext(servletContext);
        if (rootAppContext != null) {
            servletContext.addListener(new YourListenerHere());
        }
        else {
            this.logger.debug("No ContextLoaderListener registered, as "
                    + "createRootApplicationContext() did not "
                    + "return an application context");
        }
    }
```

Finally there is a [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners) in which you can find some information about listeners and SpringApplication class. Read section

Comment: You mean that also listeners in my external jars are automatically loaded? <listener>
  <listener-class>org.granite.config.GraniteConfigListener</listener-class> 
 </listener> 
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.granite.gravity.websocket.GravityWebSocketDeployer</listener-class>
 </listener>

Comment: No that are not register automatically only both that spring uses, but you use use servletContext.addListener to add them, let me update the answer

Comment: createRootApplicationContext() method is not inherited from WebApplicationInitializer.

Comment: Read this link for further information http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners

Comment: Change it for an abstract class extends SpringBootServletInitializer, but first read the link in the previous post

Comment: Finally according to the specs the injection could be done using just @Bean as this link implies http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-add-a-servlet-filter-or-servletcontextlistener

Comment: Using `SpringBootServletInitializer` when you're using an embedded container is a little unusual. As stated in its javadoc, it's intended "to run a SpringApplication from a traditional WAR deployment".

Answer (score 12):

Spring Boot will automatically register any `@Beans` of the following types with the servlet container:

- ServletContextAttributeListener
- ServletRequestListener
- ServletRequestAttributeListener
- HttpSessionAttributeListener
- HttpSessionListener
- ServletContextListener

For example, to register `GravityWebSocketDeployer` which is a `ServletContextListener` add a `@Bean` method to your configuration class:

```
@Bean
public GravityWebSocketDeployer gravityWebSocketDeployer() {
    return new GravityWebSocketDeployer();
}
```

Comment: Section 27.3 of the current Spring Boot documentation mentions this with regard to the Embedded Tomcat servlet container, but is this true also for a standalone servlet container? I don't see any documentation to that effect, but it seems to work for me on a stand-alone Tomcat instance...

Comment: Yes, it will work when deploying to a standalone container as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also Spring Boot will automatically register any @Bean extend of HttpServlet;

```
   @Bean
   public ServletRegistrationBean axisServletRegistrationBean() {
      ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new AxisServlet(), "/services/*");
      registration.addUrlMappings("*.jws");
      return registration;
   }
```